# How can I use a custom function in a nested golang template?

Tags: templates, go

I have a webpage consisting of one layout.html and one content.html. Both contain calls to a custom function for translating strings.

When I call template.ParseFiles, the content is included into the layout and is served, but only strings in layout.html are translated while the strings from content.html disappear.

This works fine when I use single html files, but I can't get it work with nested files.

main.go

```
func executeMultiTmpl(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "index": lookup,
  }
  tmpl, err := template.New("example.html").Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(
    "dev/html/example/layout.html",
    "dev/html/example/content.html",
  )
   var tpl bytes.Buffer
   err = tmpl.Execute(&tpl ,Translation)
   if err != nil {
    panic(err)
   }
}
```

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example Title - {{index . "About"}}</title>
</head>
<body>

{{ template "content.html" }}

</body>
</html>
```

content.html

```
<h2>{{index . "Some headline"}}</h2>
```

The file content.html is nested inside of layout.html. Afterwards the function **lookup** receives a map **Translation** and translates all strings in the layout.html file which are surrounded by {{index . }}. Unfortunately, the strings in the file content.html are not translated.

I know the function **lookup** is called, but it receives an empty **Translation** map.

When I remove the custom function and run it with the standard **index** function, I get a panic: executing "content.html" at : error calling index: index of untyped nil

Comment: You're not passing anything to the content template. `{{ template "content.html" . }}` <-- see the dot?

Comment: Works like a charm. I guess I'm not aloud to upvote you but thank you:)